# PyQt5 QSqlDatabase doesn't open without any text error

Tags: python, database, qtsql, pyqt5

I wrote own class extends QSqlDatabase:

```
class Model(QSqlDatabase):

    def __init__(self):
        QSqlDatabase.__init__(self, 'QSQLITE')
        self.setDatabaseName(QSettings().value('DB_PATH'))
        if not self.open():
            print(self.lastError().text())
            raise DBConnectError()
```

but open() returns False, and lastError() doesn't show anything. What is my mistake?

Python 3.3
PyQt 5

Comment: Print out the value of QSettings().value('DB_PATH') – it may not be what you think it is.

Comment: C:\Users\User\YandexDisk\Projects\Strains\db.sqlite - full path

Comment: Have you tried using the recommended constructor method? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtsql/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase

Comment: I have, nothing changed. open in False, path is good, error is empty

Comment: Have you opened the database using the sqlite command line tools to prove it is a valid database?

Comment: Yes, database is valid. I made it with sqliteman

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I don.t know why, but method addDatabaseName doesn't accept full path. When I wrote relative path (only 'db.sqlite') database connected successfully.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Have to ask the obvious question: that is the correct full path? I.e. `dir` of that path works?